# Format the array with hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I  have to get array like this

```
 [{"social"=>"linkedin", "count"=>1},
 {"social"=>"twitter",   "count"=>1}, 
 {"social"=>"facebook",  "count"=>0}]
```

from this array

```
=> [{"twitter"=>1, "linkedin"=>1, "facebook"=>0}]
```

How I can do it?

Comment: @sawa SQL query returns me array, but I need to format it before using in view. That's all) What is not clear? I got answer) tnx

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: By the way, the answer you accepted does not give what you want.

Comment: Emm, why? `result => [{"twitter"=>1, "linkedin"=>1, "facebook"=>0}]` `result[0].map { |key, value| {'social' => key, 'count'=>value } }`
`=> [{"social"=>"twitter", "count"=>1},
 {"social"=>"linkedin", "count"=>1},
 {"social"=>"facebook", "count"=>0}]`

Comment: It looks like I wanted

Comment: @sawa - I think after my edit, you can put your mind at ease...

Comment: Oh, Man). It was a small mistake in text because of "copy-paste". Sorry, guys))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try:

```
arr = [{"twitter"=>1, "linkedin"=>1, "facebook"=>0}]

arr[0].map { |key, value| {'social' => key, 'count'=>value } }
# => [{"soсial"=>"twitter", "count"=>1}, {"soсial"=>"linkedin", "count"=>1}, {"soсial"=>"facebook", "count"=>0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like below:

```
[{"twitter"=>1, "linkedin"=>1, "facebook"=>0}].first.to_a.map do |a|
  { "sotial" => a[0], "count" => a[1] } 
end
```